# Where does TrackRequest() data show up in the portal?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have a console application logging to TrackRequest in a TelemetryClient, but I can't figure out what tile to display in the Azure portal to see the data.
Is there some guidance that lists each method, the data, and what tile exposes it?

Answer (score 2):

With the following code in a console app:

```
 TelemetryClient client = new TelemetryClient(new TelemetryConfiguration()
  {
                InstrumentationKey = "<your ikey>",
                TelemetryChannel = new InMemoryChannel()

 });
  client.TrackRequest("Hello", DateTimeOffset.Now, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), "200", true);
  Console.ReadLine();
```

Request data will appear on main overview page and in search results.

[image]

Comment: presuming that the app you created is other or asp.net (and maybe java?)  if you created a store app, ios app in the portal, the main overview page will not show requests, but you will be able to see them in search.

Comment: in general, most of the `Track*` methods corresponds to one of the types in alex's screenshot of the search page.